# Speed and size of vendor prefix CSS workarounds (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a site using Twitter Bootstrap, H5BP and other bits and pieces including Modernizr...which references Yepnope.js...which references [Prefix Free](https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree).

The (compiled) Bootstrap CSS is full of vendor prefix workarounds, which I largely appreciate--I don't want to manually figure all that out myself but it also makes it bloated. I am skilled enough to omit unneeded CSS but I'd like to know if it would be faster if left the vendor prefixes in the CSS or used Prefix Free.

I found Prefix Free through Modernizr, via the Yepnope.js link on the site so I'd likely be using all three but in all honesty, I probably won't create explicit rules to support antiquated browsers (as you can with Modernizr).

I'd be ok with supporting the basics that Prefix Free is intended for (IE 9+) if using it would be faster than leaving the Bootstrap CSS largely as is.

Would it load faster if I leave all the workarounds in the CSS as is or strip the vendor prefixes and add them dynamically via Prefix Free?

Anybody dealt with this before?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only benefit there would be of removing the vendor specific CSS styles is just really reducing the size of the CSS file. The fact a browser uses a browser specific style doesn't slow down the rendering process, nor does a browser encountering a specific style that isn't suited to that browser (basically Firefox coming across an IE filter).

However, I think it would take longer to load a page if you are using a third party script to produce the vendor specific styles that you have removed from Bootstrap. Bootstrap, as far as I know, has been optimised to be as fast as possible. So really, I would avoid hacking it and removing the vendor specific styles.

Comment: While I have been pleased with Bootstrap as a starting point, the CSS is a bit bloated and uses 'expensive' selectors sometimes as per this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS). I am much less familiar with JavaScript so I have no way of knowing if it would be 'faster' to run a script (as above) or leave all the vendor prefixes as they are now. Either way, when done developing I will be minifying and such.